# error : to_string was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, solaris

I am compiling the code on solaris 5.11.
G++ version is 4.8.2.

The same code works on Ubuntu but gives the error: 'to_string() was not declared in this scope' on solaris.

I went through many links and tried the following things:

1. Adding 'std::' before to_string(). This gives error - 'to_string is not a member of std'
2. Added 'std=c++11' or 'std=c++0x' while compilation.

Both the above things do not work.

Is there anything related to Solaris?

The actual code was very huge. So simulating the error in sample code below.

temp.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    int i = 10;
    str = "john age is " + to_string(i);
    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

command: g++ temp.cpp -std=c++0x -o temp

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @steve please refer the code above

Answer (score 4):

For GCC 4.8.2 the `to_string` functions are defined conditionally, according to the following:

```
#if ((__cplusplus >= 201103L) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99) \
     && !defined(_GLIBCXX_HAVE_BROKEN_VSWPRINTF))
```

The `GLIBCXX_USE_C99` macro depends on a large number of C99 functions being supported by the OS, so presumably the necessary C99 library functions were not found when building GCC on Solaris. So the `to_string` definitions are absent.

In current versions of GCC the condition is more fine-grained, and checks whether the C99 functions are defined in C++98 mode and C++11, so that the absence of any C99 function doesn't disable everything:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
//...
#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDIO
```

It's not possible to backport these improvements to GCC 4.8, so you might need to update to at least GCC 6.

Answer (score 0):

compile using std=c++11 as below

g++ -std=c++11 filename.cc

**Note :  your compiler must support  c++11**

Comment: Above is also not working. Compiler supports c++11. I checked __cplusplus value which is 201103L.